# Cannot Delete Anything on Site in Internet Explorer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

so I had finished making my sites. One issue one of my peers brought up was that if using Internet Explorer, you cannot delete anything.

For example, I can create items just fine in Internet Explorer. In my site contents I created a new custom list called "test". I click on the ellipses in the top right of the app, and click remove and nothing happens, a small grey box outlines the ellipses and the web app stays there.

[image]

Now if I want to delete that web app, I must open up Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome.

What is causing this? And how do I fix it? I have not been able to find anything online about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here're some tips for you to troubleshooting the issue.

1.Clear IE browser cache.

2.Upgrade IE browser to the latest version.

If the issue persists, you could try to uninstall the IE browser then re-install again.